# how to save multiple Cell array values in one .csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, nested-loops, file-handling, cell-array

I have been working on making a database which contains images and their preset values and other important parameters. But unfortunately, I'm not being able to save the initial data of say `10` images in one `.csv` file. I have made the code that runs fine with creating `.csv` file but saving the last value and overwriting all the previous values. I gave also once modified that is comment down in the code using `sprintf` but it make `.csv` file for every iteration separately. But i want to make one `.csv` file containing `7` column with all the respective values.

My code is below and output of my code is attached [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JPS.png).
Please someone guide me how to make single `.csv` file with `10` values for instance (could be increased to hundreds in final database) to save in 1 `.csv` file.

```
clc
clear all

myFolder = 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PixROIDirectory\PixelLabelData_1';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.png'); % Change to whatever pattern you need
theFiles = dir(filePattern);

load('gTruthPIXDATA.mat','gTruth')
gTruth.LabelDefinitions;
for i=1:10
%gTruth.LabelData{i,1};

baseFileName = theFiles(i).name;
fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
imageArray = imread(fullFileName);
oUt = regionprops(imageArray,'BoundingBox');
Y = floor(oUt.BoundingBox);
X_axis = Y(1);
Y_axis = Y(2);
Width = Y(3);
Height = Y(4);

CLASS = gTruth.LabelDefinitions{1,1};
JPG = gTruth.DataSource.Source{i,1};
PNG = gTruth.LabelData{i,1};
OUTPUT = [JPG X_axis Y_axis Width Height CLASS PNG]

%     myFile = sprintf('value%d.csv',i);
%     csvwrite(myFile,OUTPUT);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fprintf (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).

You will need to open your output file to be written, then you can append lines to it through each iteration

Simple example:

```
A = [1:10];                   % made up a matrix of numbers
fid = fopen('test.csv','w');  % open a blank csv and set as writable
for i = 1:length(A)           % loop through the matrix
     fprintf(fid,'%i\n',A(i)); % print each integer, then a line break \n
end
fclose(fid);                   % close the file for writing
```